# Printing structures using loop

Tags: c

How to print structure contents using `for-loop`? If pointers, how to assign pointer to structure? I have attached code that I made that makes a structure using data that user inputs, and prints them out in an orderly fashion. My problem is that you have to write a lot of `printf()` and `gets_s()` statements to receive and print input. I feel like it would be easier to do this using a `for-loop`. I tried to make a `for-loop` as you can see in the code using pointers, but it doesn't compile, and I'm pretty sure that it is the wrong way to assign pointers to structures.

TL;DR: How to print structure contents using for-loop? If pointers, how to assign pointer to structure?

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define maxName 50
#define maxNation 50
#define maxAge 100

struct astronaut
{
    char firstName[maxName];
    char lastName[maxName];
    char nation[maxNation];
    int age = 0;
    char missionName[maxAge];
    int missionYear[50];
};

int main()
{
    int i = 0;
    struct astronaut candidate1;
    struct astronaut candidate2;
    struct astronaut candidate3;
    struct astronaut mission1;
    struct astronaut mission2;
    struct astronaut mission3;

    printf("Please enter the first name of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate1.firstName);
    printf("Please enter the last name of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate1.lastName);
    printf("Please enter the nationality of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate1.nation);
    printf("Please enter the age of the candidate: ");
    scanf("%d", &candidate1.age);

    printf("Please enter the first name of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate2.firstName);
    printf("Please enter the last name of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate2.lastName);
    printf("Please enter the nationality of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate2.nation);
    printf("Please enter the age of the candidate: ");
    scanf("%d", &candidate2.age);

    printf("Please enter the first name of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate3.firstName);
    printf("Please enter the last name of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate3.lastName);
    printf("Please enter the nationality of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(candidate3.nation);
    printf("Please enter the age of the candidate: ");
    scanf("%d", &candidate3.age);

    printf("Enter a Mission Name: ");
    gets_s(mission1.missionName);
    printf("Enter the year the mission was conducted: ");
    scanf("%d", &mission1.missionYear);

    printf("Enter a Mission Name: ");
    gets_s(mission2.missionName);
    printf("Enter the year the mission was conducted: ");
    scanf("%d", &mission2.missionYear);

    printf("Enter a Mission Name: ");
    gets_s(mission3.missionName);
    printf("Enter the year the mission was conducted: ");
    scanf("%d", &mission3.missionYear);

    struct astronaut *ptr;
    struct candidate *ptr;

//  printf("\n\tAstronaut Candidate Database\n");
//  printf("Name: %s %s \t Age: %d \t Nationality: %s\n",     candidate1.firstName, candidate1.lastName, candidate1.age, candidate1.nation);
//  printf("Name: %s %s \t Age: %d \t Nationality: %s\n",     candidate2.firstName, candidate2.lastName, candidate2.age, candidate2.nation);
//  printf("Name: %s %s \t Age: %d \t Nationality: %s\n",     candidate3.firstName, candidate3.lastName, candidate3.age, candidate3.nation);
//  printf("\n\tAstronaut Mission Database\n");
//  printf("Mission Name: %s \t Year: %d\n", mission1.missionName,     mission1.missionYear);
//  printf("Mission Name: %s \t Year: %d\n", mission2.missionName,     mission2.missionYear);
//  printf("Mission Name: %s \t Year: %d\n", mission3.missionName,     mission3.missionYear);

    for (int index = 0; index < 5; index++)
    {
        printf("Name: %s %s \t Age: %d \t Nationality: %s\n",     *ptr.firstName, *ptr.lastName, *ptr.age, *ptr.nation);
        ptr++;
    }

    _getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't print individual variables using a loop (well, technically you can but that would be system dependent / UB). You need to use an array or something like a linked list.

Comment: I would write a function that accepts a pointer to a `struct astronaut` that accepts all the user input. Then you can just have one-liners calling that function with each `struct astronaut` you have... different function for each `candidate` and `mission` maybe.. but it looks like to me you need 2 separate structs .. one for astronauts and one for missions.

Comment: 1) Don't use `conio.h`. 2) Post code that compiles. If it does not, post the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need 2 structs. An `astronaut` and a `mission` aren't the same thing.  As it is now, you have several unused fields depending on whether you're entering data for an `astronaut` or a `mission`.  You could do something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define maxName 50
#define maxNation 50
#define maxAge 100

struct astronaut
{
    char firstName[maxName];
    char lastName[maxName];
    char nation[maxNation];
    int age;
};

struct mission
{
    char missionName[maxAge];
    int missionYear;  // why do you have an array of 50 ints for the missionYear?
};

void enter_candidate_data(struct candidate* cand)
{
    // not famliar with gets_s .. I would use fgets here, you can read the manpage on that if you desire
    printf("Please enter the first name of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(cand->firstName);
    printf("Please enter the last name of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(cand->lastName);
    printf("Please enter the nationality of the candidate: ");
    gets_s(cand->nation);
    printf("Please enter the age of the candidate: ");
    scanf("%d", &(cand->age));
}

void enter_mission_data(struct mission* mis)
{
    printf("Enter a Mission Name: ");
    gets_s(mis->missionName);
    printf("Enter the year the mission was conducted: ");
    scanf("%d", &(mis->missionYear));
}

int main()
{
    int i;
    struct astronaut candidates[3];
    struct mission missions[3];

    for (i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        enter_candidate_data(&(candidates[i]));
        // you can put this in a separate loop if you want to enter all
        // candidate data first
        enter_mission_data(&(missions[i]));
    }

    // you could also write functions to print the data instead, depends on
    // how you want it all presented

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        printf("Name: %s %s \t Age: %d \t Nationality: %s\n",
            candidates[i].firstName, candidates[i].lastName, candidates[i].nation);
        printf("Mission Name: %s, year %d\n", missions[i].missionName,
            missions[i].missionYear);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You may want a number of missions (or even just one) associated with a particular astronaut. If so, I would define the data structures like this

```
#define MAX_ASTRONAUT_MISSIONS 20

struct mission
{
    char missionName[maxAge];
    int missionYear;
};

struct astronaut
{
    char firstName[maxName];
    char lastName[maxName];
    char nation[maxNation];
    int age;
    struct mission missions[MAX_ASTRONAUT_MISSIONS];
};
```

This will allow you to associate MAX_ASTRONAUT_MISSION missions with each astronaut.  Or, more realistically, a single mission could be associated with several astronauts.  In that case, you may want data structures more like this

```
struct mission
{
    char missionName[maxAge];
    int missionYear;
};

struct astronaut
{
    char firstName[maxName];
    char lastName[maxName];
    char nation[maxNation];
    int age;
    // using a pointer to missions will allow you to create one mission, and
    // all the astronauts on that mission could get a pointer to it,
    // designating they were all on that singular mission.
    struct mission* missions[MAX_ASTRONAUT_MISSIONS];
};
```